# Can't import components

Tags: android, react-native

im just learning how to use react native but im having a little trouble when im trying to import an external component, i got an unexpected token (13:6) error. i jsut cant figure it out what im doing woring, please help me and show me what is wrong and why i cant import the component .

thank you

this is my code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import ComponenteTexto from './componenteTexto';



export default class primero extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      <componenteTexto/>

        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu,{'\n'}

          <Text style={styles.instructions1}>



              te amo tefita {5*2}
          </Text>


        </Text>



      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'skyblue',
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
  instructions1: {
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'black',
    marginBottom: 8,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('primero', () => primero);
```

```html
`
```

and this is the component i am trying to import

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
View,
  Text

} from 'react-native';


export default class ComponenteTexto extends Component {
  render() {

    return{
      <View>
        <Text>
        Prueba
        </Text>
      </View>
    }

  }
}
```

and this is what i get as error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Aao.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ComponenteTexto` component is using `{ }` instead of `( )` in the return statement so it's not returning the expected type of object. Try changing it to:

```
return (
  <View>
    <Text>
    Prueba
    </Text>
  </View>
)
```